# AttributeError: module 'rethinkdb' has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: python-3.x, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I am using the RethinkDB in my Jupyter Python Notebook.
I have installed the RethinkDB server for my Windows setup.
And server version is

```
C:\Users\rethinkdb-2.3.6>rethinkdb --version
rethinkdb 2.3.6-windows (MSC 190024215)
```

On the client side, I see the rethinkDB is : rethinkdb==2.4.2.post1.
So when use my python code to connect to the DB which i have already started on my windows server, it gives the error as:

```
=>self.conn = r.connect('localhost', 28015)
AttributeError: module 'rethinkdb' has no attribute 'connect'
```

I have seen some earlier posts where there are comments that the way we connect to RethinkDB has changed from 2.4.X and I already tried the code options below but they did not help:

```py
import rethinkdb as rdb
r = rdb.RethinkDB()
self.conn = r.connect('localhost', 28015)
```

Comment: Did you start the server in the terminal using `rethinkdb` command

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
from rethinkdb import RethinkDB 
r = RethinkDB()
```

then try connecting it like this,

```
r.connect( "localhost", 28015).repl()
```